# How to recognize a quote symbol (")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Enviroment: Visual Studio 2012, MVC4, Razor, Internet Application.

I have a code with search form in the "View" page...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchResult", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Search</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input name="SearchButton" type="submit" value="Search" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And then I'm sending a "model.Name" string directly to the JavaScript code using "@Model.Name".

The problem is... when I typing in the search form a quote (") symbol... for example... (10" android) I have a problem. JavaScript stops work somewhere. How can I check this "model.Name" string inside the controller is it contains (") or not and change it for JavaScript?

My JavaScript code... `url += "&keywords=@Model.Name";`
If "model.Name" is... 10" android ...will it work correct?

Comment: I dont see anything out of the ordinary, where is this javascript you speak of

Comment: Please show your javascript code.

Comment: I've add it at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Javascript, I would encode with "escape", but it is best practice to replace the " (double) quotes with the XML representation `&quot;`

As for server-side, I use Web Protection Library from Microsoft to handle that part,
http://wpl.codeplex.com/

> Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(dr["message"].ToString()))

Comment: I've install this library, but I don't understand where and how should I use it.

Comment: This was the article that helped me -http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx

Comment: I've understood. But this method returns "10&quot; android". Actually nothing will help. I think, I have to do this work in JavaScript.